# Ler Ini de um site

Tags: delphi

Quero ler o arquivo ini de um site, mas não estou conseguindo.
Tentei assim:

```
inicheck := 'http://pokestage.ddns.net/patch/CHECK.INI';
conf2 := TIniFile.Create(IdHTTP3.Get(inicheck));
version2 := conf2.ReadString('CONFIG', 'TVERSION', '');
```

Mas não está funcionando.
Como deve ser feito?

Testei assim:

```
var
  conf2 : TIniFile;
  version2 : string;
  inicheck : string;
  path : string;
  tempfile : TFileStream;
begin
  path := extractFilepath(application.exename);
  inicheck := 'http://pokestage.ddns.net/patch/CHECK.INI';
  tempfile := TFileStream.Create('SCHECK.INI', fmCreate);
  try
    tempfile.Position:=0;
    IdHTTP3.Get(inicheck, tempfile);
    tempfile.Free;
    conf2 := TIniFile.Create(path+'\SCHECK.INI');
    version2 := conf2.ReadString('CONFIG', 'TVERSION', '');
  finally
    conf2.Free;
  end;
  ShowMessage('Client '+version);
  ShowMessage('Servidor '+version2)
```

E não deu, não to vendo diferença entre o meu e o seu. 
O client, funcionou, sendo que é a mesma coisa.

Edit: consegui, estava botando o tempfile.free; no lugar errado, tem que fechar antes de criar o ini. Ja ajeitei no exemplo.

Comment: Sim, mas funcionou. rs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O método `Create` de `TIniFile` requer um arquivo existente em disco. Então não funcionar tentar passar para ele o que você está obtendo com o componente `IdHTTP` sem antes salvá-lo em disco para então abrir com o `TIniFile`.

Logo, experimente algo como:

```
var
  fileIni: TIniFile;
  response: TFileStream;
  version: string;
begin
  response := TFileStream.Create(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'iniFile.ini', fmCreate);
  try
    response.Position := 0;
    IdHTTP.Get('http://pokestage.ddns.net/patch/CHECK.INI', response);
  finally
    response.Free;
  end;

  fileIni := TIniFile.Create(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'iniFile.ini');
  try
    version := fileIni.ReadString('CONFIG', 'TVERSION', '');
    showMessage(version);
  finally
    fileIni.Free;
  end;

  // faça o que precisa com a variável "version"
end;
```

Testei esse código com a sua url e funcionou.

[image: Teste]

Detalhe que você está usando **'CONFIG'** e **'TVERSION'** para ler o valor, mas no seu arquivo é **'CONF'** e **'VERSION'**.

Comment: Retornou esse erro: variable might not have been initialized

Comment: Ainda não funcionou, é Delphi 7, Indy 10, não retorna erro, apenas não pega o valor.

Comment: Olha no edit, estou fazendo praticamente igual, mas não ta indo